# Conda Installation Issue

Tags: anaconda

I installed anaconda following the docs. However when I type conda --version in the terminal, I will not get any output. Also no output for conda list .

I found out that, I already installed anaconda before and I tried to remove everything even the .contium folders, updated in .bashrc, but I am not getting any output for any conda command.

Comment: Please, let me know if my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and write (I suppose you have anaconda for pyhton3):

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

If it works, then use the file .bashrc (hidden file), located in the home directory, runs codes every time a new terminal is opened.

Then add a line on it:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: It didnt worked. I have miniconda2 installed. I can see the following appended in the .bashrc # added by Miniconda2 4.3.21 installer
export PATH="/home/kranthi/miniconda2/bin:$PATH"

Comment: @kranthisai, So i suggest you to install anaconda. It works for me.

Comment: yeah I tried that too. Never had these issues before. Looks weird to me. I moved to docker. Thank you..